# Silverstripe 3.1.x Change Password: Force Admin to Confirm Current Password

Tags: silverstripe

Can anyone tell me whether SilverStripe has a configuration option which can be enabled in order to force admin users to have to confirm their current password when they try to change their password?

I've just received results back from a security scan for a client project and one of the Medium-risk security issues flagged (to be fixed within 60 days) was the following:

> ### Description
>
> **Observation:**
>
> Admin users are not required to enter their current password when changing their password.
>
> **Sample Affected URL:**
>   http://yourdomain.com/admin/myprofile
>
> ** Screenshot:**
>   http://www.silverstripe.org/assets/Uploads/admin-myprofile.jpg
>
> **Impact:**
>   A malicious user through the use of session hijacking, a man in the middle attack, 
>   cross-site request forgery attacks or finding an unattended logged in session could 
>   change an account password without knowing the current password. Also, when a user 
>   cannot change their username or password, they cannot be proactive in guarding against 
>   the user credentials being compromised.
>
> **Recommendation:** 
>   It is a best practice to allow a user to alter his username and password. Further, it 
>   should require a user to provide his current password in conjunction with providing the 
>   new password to revalidate the identity of the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I can't find any existing solutions. I imagine we would need to extend [`ConfirmedPasswordField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ConfirmedPasswordField.html).

Comment: Hmm personally i would make the admin section force https for traffic. If the passwords are just posted over the http when logging in it would be much logical for the attacker use that instead of blatantly changing the password what would give an glue for the users that their login details are compromised. Silverstripe takes quite care of protecting from XSS attacts so using https would cover the basis quite nicely.. Thought i would like to hear the core teams take on this also :)

Comment: Enforcing HTTPS for the admin could be enforced by .htaccess / nginx configuration. Concerning the password confirmation, you might want to ask on the dev mailing list to get this into core, which might be a good idea: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/silverstripe-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the short term, you can use the DataExtension class to extend this functionality for the Member class without modifying the core. Have a look at [this reference page](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension).